# New wired connection profile just appeared

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, connection

System : Ubuntu 18.04.1

I usually connect through the 'Wired connection 2' which was my only connection profile on the network manager.

Today, when I logged in my computer, a new profile was there 'Wired connection 3' and the whole ethernet connection doesn't work anymore (even through 'Wired connection 2') - I'm using wireless to post this right now.

My question is : how and why are these connection profile created?

Thanks

Edit: More information on my setup, I'm also using a docking station (lenovo) which is the relay of my ethernet connection.

Comment: Perhaps you installed some software that created new profile ?

Comment: I haven't installed anything new on the computer.. kinda appeared out of nowhere